# How to access scanner device using wifi in iphone application (same as wifi printer)?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, printing

I want to access scanner device in my iphone app via wifi just like printer (as we do for UIPrinterInteractionController)

there are already several apps available on itunes like iPrint&Scan etc.

Please help me out, I get stuck on this.

thanks,
Mrunal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use **UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols**

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.  I have read about UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols. But in that we need to add all protocols and ports for the attached device. For Wifi Printer and Wifi Scanner we never use such things. I have seen code for Wifi Printer, there are inbuilt libraries available.

Answer (score 0):

check this one 
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SampleScannerApp/Listings/Controller_h.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007644-Controller_h-DontLinkElementID_3

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. I have checked that code but it is for Mac OS, not for iPhone OS. :(  Can we use the same code for iOS devices? If Yes, please let me know how?

Answer (score 0):

check  **External accessory framework** it will be useful